# Best Practices in using a lock

Tags: c#, locking

Suppose I have the following property in some class, and its purpose is to be used as a lock.

```
protected object SyncRoot { get; private set; }
```

Anyways, regardless of how and if this was set. What is best practice to go about using it if it is, in fact, set?

Since lock does not work with null objects, should I handle it like this?

```
lock (SyncRoot ?? new object())
    SomeMethod();
```

Or should I check for null like this?

```
if (SyncRoot != null)
    lock (SyncRoot)
        SomeMethod();
else
    SomeMethod();
```

If it is, in fact, set, I'd want to use it to lock. Otherwise, I don't care. Is the first solution inefficient or redundant in anyway?

EDIT: All these answers are good. However, I can only pick one. Given my situation as discussed with Luke, there is no reason why my SyncRoot should be null. The overhead of a lock in a single threaded environment is no biggy, but necessary if in a multi-threaded one.

(Vote ups for all 4 of ya) Thank you all for your speedy replies.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I normally use a private member variable not a property, ie

```
private static object MyLock = new object();
```

This way its always initialised.

You can also use a non static version such as

```
private readonly object MyLock = new object();
```

Comment: In my parent class, this property is set given some condition. It is my intent to use this variable or property in derived classes if said condition is true.
Would you think that lock(SyncRoot ?? new object()) comes with too much overhead?

Comment: @Beljoda, a lock object is just a `new object()` -- why would you ever bother leaving it null?  (why would you not just initialize it when it's declared, eliminating this concern by default?)

Comment: @Luke, It's for my manager class that interfaces to me access to a scripting language. This lock object is null if I initially decide not to automatically compile the scripts. If I do decide to set it to auto-compile, I use this lock so that I don't call a method in the middle of it being redefined.

Comment: @Beljoda, but why not just *always* lock?  Are you afraid of the overhead?  It is quite frankly a rare situation where the overhead of locking provides a defense to this sort of additional complexity.

Comment: @Luke, Hmm... your right. This lock object is set when there is a chance of multiple threads running on this manager class (since automatically compiling code includes multiple threads spawned by events). Internal to this manager class, only one thread would be running code in this class if auto-compile is not set.
And the overhead of a lock isn't terrible hindering. 
I might as well lock every time.

Comment: @Beljoda lock(SyncRoot ?? new object())  isnt a terribly good option, when you are locking on 'new object()' it isnt going to have any effect at all. a lock only really works because the object is shared by multiple threads, in this case the object will not be shared at all

Answer (score 14):

Synchronizing on

```
SyncRoot ?? new object()
```

makes no sense, because if `SyncRoot` is `null`, each thread will get a new object every time. Synchronizing on separate objects has no effect: threads will continue right away, because nobody else could possibly synchronize on the same `new` object.

You should initialize `SyncRoot` in the constructor, before the first thread tries to obtain a lock.

Comment: does synchronizing to a new object come with any repercussions like hindrance in speed?

Comment: @Beljoda, the performance ramifications of synchronizing on `new object()` is moot since it is a completely useless idiom.

Comment: speed doesn't matter; if every thread that passes through your code creates a new lock object, then your code is not protected from multiple threads accessing the protected resource. To get the threads to line up and access the protected resource one at a time, they have to all lock on the SAME object instance.

Comment: @Beljoda Synchronizing on a new object is equivalent to having no synchronization at all: the only reason one thread would get a lock and the other would wait is that they look at the *same* object. This will not happen if each thread gets a new object on which to synchronize.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, Right. So, I should just use your solution regardless if my class is used within a single or multi threaded application. 
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The first will be a problem, as it will not lead to any good synchronization:

```
lock (SyncRoot ?? new object())
    SomeMethod();
```

The reason being is that if you create a new object and **not** assign it to `SyncRoot` it will be placed on the heap, but there will be no reference to it. So when another thread comes, it will not find it... It becomes absolutely useless and it won't block any access to the critical section.

The second approach will work, though I really cannot understand why you would like to use the lock if it is available only.

Answer (score 3):

From documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

> In general, avoid locking on a public type, or instances beyond your code's control. The common constructs lock (this), lock (typeof (MyType)), and lock ("myLock") violate this guideline:
>
> - lock (this) is a problem if the instance can be accessed publicly.
> - lock (typeof (MyType)) is a problem if MyType is publicly accessible.
> - lock("myLock") is a problem because any other code in the process using the same string, will share the same lock.
>
> **Best practice** is to define a **private object to lock on**, or a **private
>   static object variable** to protect data common to all instances.

Sample:

```
 class Account
{
    decimal balance;
    private Object thisLock = new Object();

    public void Withdraw(decimal amount)
    {
        lock (thisLock)
        {
            if (amount > balance)
            {
                throw new Exception("Insufficient funds");
            }
            balance -= amount;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to always initialize the lock object, before any consumer of the lock object has a chance to use it. The cost to always allocate the lock object is small, and the cost of taking the lock is small when there is no thread contention.

So adding lock/no lock checks all over your code will double the complexity of your code and probably introduce subtle threading bugs but will probably not produce any tangible performance benefit.

Simplify your code: always take the lock.

Answer (score 1):

If requiring threadsafe access of objects like queues, sets and Dictionaries, I lock on that object itself, no need to have a separate lock object.  Best if the queue, set or Dictionary is private or readonly so that you can be sure it's always the same object.

Sample:

```
class Processor
{
    readonly Queue<int> processQueue = new Queue<int>();

    public void AddToQueue(int index)
    {
        lock (processQueue)
        {
            processQueue.Enqueue(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you just use a  [ConcurrentQueue<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=net-5.0)