# Restart Process Hangs in Exited Handler by Dispatcher.Invoke()

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

It's a WPF project based on .net 4.7.2.

In order to restart a process(not the main process itself, but other process, which was launched by the main process), process.Start() is called in process' Exited event handler.

Simplified code is as follows:

```
public MainWindow()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        Process process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = *<path to a bat file>*,
                WorkingDirectory = *<folder to the bat file>*,
                UseShellExecute = true,
            },
            EnableRaisingEvents = true,
        };
        
        
        // register handler
        process.Exited += (sender, args) =>
        {
            
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                process.Start();          // restart after be killed
            });
            Console.Out.WriteLine("OnExit Finish");
        };

       // start for the first time
        process.Start();
        
       // wait and kill
       Thread.sleep(2000);
       process.CloseMainWindow();
       process.Kill();
  }
```

The problem is **Start()** in Dispatcher.Invoke does not returns though the process is restarted, which means **it gets stuck**.
After digging I found something, but can still not make it through.

1. It hangs on a lock in Process:

This method comes from donet framework source code. It is called through several calls rooted by Process.Start().

[The whole file can be found here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs)

```
 private void EnsureWatchingForExit()
    {
      if (this.watchingForExit)
        return;
      lock (this)    // ***** IT HANGS *****
      {
        if (this.watchingForExit)
          return;
        this.watchingForExit = true;
        try
        {
          this.waitHandle = (WaitHandle) new ProcessWaitHandle(this.m_processHandle);
          this.registeredWaitHandle = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(this.waitHandle, new WaitOrTimerCallback(this.CompletionCallback), (object) null, -1, true);
        }
        catch
        {
          this.watchingForExit = false;
          throw;
        }
      }
    }
```

2. Use *Dispatcher.InvokeAsync()* instead of *Invoke()* can solve the hang.

**lock block** in C# is short for Monitor.Enter(), which is reenterant. And Invoke() guarantees that its the same thread as it runs to the lock.

I am curious on why it gets stuck ?

Comment: `lock(this)` is bad practice, `this` reference can be changed outside

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best Practices in using a lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788582/best-practices-in-using-a-lock)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski It's probably not. The EnsureWatchingForExit code piece is not write by me. It is from donet framework source code.

Comment: I'd venture that reusing the existing `Process` instance is probably a bad idea. What happens if you discard the old `Process` instance and start a new one, instead of reusing?

Comment: Maybe try setting process.EnableRaisingEvents = false (to clear the wait handle) and then resetting it to true before calling Start in your exit handler?

Comment: @spender Sure, reusing process is bad practice, but I have not got a better choice. I am implementing a *ProcessExecutor*, in which process instance is injected by parameter, and then be used in the ProcessExecutor. As a process instance has so many fields, I did not find a proper way to copy them all, so I reuse the process instance.

Comment: @Mufaka It is still not work : (

Comment: @SuN Instead of injecting a concrete process instance, why not inject a delegate ( `Func<Process>` ) or a factory that, when called, returns a process instance? Now you can leave the setup of the process as a responsibility elsewhere, but still get a new Process when you want to restart.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
public static void Restart()
            {
                try
                {
    
                    var m = (Application.Current.MainWindow as Window);
                    if (m != null)
                    {
                        m.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                        m.Close();
                    }
                    Process.Start(Application.ResourceAssembly.Location);
                    Application.Current.Shutdown();
                }
                catch { }
            }
```

**EDIT**

As per the comments, if you want to `Start` be called after proper termination, you should call the [WaitForExit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netcore-3.1) Method in the process object. This ensures that the process is completely killed before restarting.

Comment: It seems it restart current process. But I need to restart other process.

Comment: To restart other process use `processObject.Kill()` then `Process.Start(patheToProcess);`

Comment: Yes, it did. But it gets stuck as described. The resason why Start() is called in OnExited handler, not just follows the Kill() statement is I need Start() be called strictly after previous process terminated. Kill() may returns before process is actually terminated.

Comment: You will want to call `WaitForExit` on the process object as in the edit on the answer.